# C# Check string for specific length of numbers

Tags: c#

I have the ability to search and return files in a given file location. I also have the ability to return a number sequence from the file name as such:

```
   public List<AvailableFile> GetAvailableFiles(string rootFolder)
    {

        List<AvailableFile> files = new List<AvailableFile>();
        if (Directory.Exists(rootFolder))
        {
            Log.Info("Checking folder: " + rootFolder + " for files");
            try
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder))
                {
                    files = FileUpload.CreateFileList(f);
                    var getNumbers = new String(f.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(getNumbers);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Log.Fatal("GetAvailableFiles failed: " + excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
```

What I want to do now is only return a sequence of numbers that is exactly 8 characters long. For example a file with the name `New File1 12345678 123` I'm only caring about getting `12345678` back.

How can I modify my method to achieve this?

Comment: use a Regex on f, you need to think about what happens if the file name has more than one sequence of 8 digits (12345678a12345678.txt for example)

Comment: The fact that theres another number before the sequence of numbers you actually want doesn't make things easier. At the moment you should get something like 112345678123 back.

Comment: getNumbers variable is a numeric string? Can't you just do `getNumbers.Length ==  8`

Comment: Also you current method presupposes there are  no numbers in the directory name (all the way back to root) as Directory.GetFiles returns full file paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex seems to be good for this:

```
var r = new Regex(".*(\\d{8})");
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder))
{
    files = FileUpload.CreateFileList(f);
    var match = r.Match(f);
    if(m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]); // be aware that index zero contains the entire matched string
    }
}
```

The regex will match the very first occurence of 8 digits and put it into the `GroupsCollection`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, index zero doesn't contain the entire inout string but only the part until the first match. Otherwise you'd have to add `.*` to it.

Comment: @MetaColon Not entirely. it obviously returns the complete *matching string*

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\d{8}");
```